# When can functions of a complex variable be integrated 'normally'?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

In our complex functions lecture notes, the lecturer integrates the complex function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ around a circle of abitrary radius (i.e. over $z = r e^{i \theta}$).

He first does a normal contour integral:

$$\oint_C f(z) dz = i \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{re^{i \theta}}{re^{i \theta}}d\theta = 2\pi i $$

But then he says 'we could have done this directly':

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z} = \ln(z) |^{re^{2\pi i}}_r = 2\pi i$$.

I don't understand why this 'direct' method is allowed. I could understand if we was integrating $f(z) = z$ instead of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ since the former is analytic everywhere (entire). However the latter is not-defined at $z=0$ so I'm not sure why this is allowed, he seems to just get the correct answer with his limits in the final step (which I don't understand why he used instead of $r$ and $r$ etc).

Comment: Egads I do not love this. It's doable, but it requires a lot more finesse than is necessary. Logs involve branch cuts so you'd need to introduce that, take a limit, argue that the limit actually matches what you should expect to get. There is a reason that the Cauchy integral formula and other such things exist: you don't have to rely on these crutches, you can use fancier techniques.

Comment: Yeah my initial thought was maybe he was using a Riemann surface or something without explicitly stating it, so I thought this wouldn't be valid in general unless you define things explicitly

Comment: @CameronWilliams This has to do with the contour passing through the branch cut, right? How would taking limits avoid or take care of this?

Comment: @CameronWilliams (+1) Hello my friend!  I hope that you're doing well and are safe and healthy.  I agree.  The OP's professor was definitely skipping to the end.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Consider the integral for any $\phi$ $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\phi+\varepsilon}^{\phi+2\pi-\varepsilon} \frac1{re^{i\theta}}\,ire^{i\theta}\,d\theta$$

Comment: @NicholasRoberts You would have to bake the branch cut into the contour. It wouldn't really be a closed contour anymore. If you take the branch cut along the negative $x$ axis, you'd have to alter your contour to omit a neighborhood of the branch cut, then shrink the neighborhood.

Comment: @MarkViola That is exactly what I had in mind but more concise and thus more better haha. Things are well! I hope things are well on your end. :)

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes.  But your description is clear (at least it is to me).

Comment: @AlexGower The point $z=0$ is not on $C$. The function $1/z$ is analytic and therefore has a primitive on any simply connected open set not containing $z=0$. The integral doesn't care about a single point. So, just remove one point from $C$ and enclose the rest in a simply connected open set. $1/z$ has a primitive there. Call that primitive $\ln$. You probably have seen the computation that when you take $\int dz$ along a path of a derivative is equal to the differences of the values of the primitive at the end points, a direct application of the Fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @AlexGower The only thing that is not present in the second computation is telling you who is $\ln$, because there are many choices, and then explaining why for that choice the difference of its values at the end points is $2\pi i$.

Comment: In addition to @plop's comment, Weierstrass' notion of "analytic continuation along a curve" is a form of "on a Riemann suface" that still does support the fundamental theorem of calculus, and so on. It's just that it's not completely elementary to say what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

I definitely don't have as much experience as people who commented, but I can maybe take a stab at rigorously justifying what your professor did.

Suppose you're trying to integrate a function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ over a curve $\gamma \subset \Omega$ with endpoints $w_1$ and $w_2$. If there exists a function $F : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ where $F' = f$, we say $F$ is a *primitive* of $f$, and by the fundamental theorem of calculus we get
$$
\tag{$\star$}
\int_\gamma f(z)dz = F(w_2) - F(w_1).
$$
The idea here is that we can still find a primitive of $1 / z$, just not on the whole complex plane. Instead, we will work with the slit plane $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0, \infty)$, where $[0, \infty)$ denotes the nonnegative real axis. Notice that $1 / z$ admits a primitive on this set, given by any branch of the logarithm with the nonnegative real axis deleted. For an arbitrarily small choice of $\varepsilon > 0$, consider the arc $\gamma_\varepsilon = \{z = re^{i\theta} : \theta \in [\varepsilon, 2\pi - \varepsilon]\} \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus [0, \infty)$. By ($\star$), we get
$$
\int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} \frac{1}{z}dz
= \log\left(re^{i(2\pi - \varepsilon)}\right) - \log\left(re^{i\varepsilon}\right)
= i(2\pi - \varepsilon) - i\varepsilon
= 2\pi i - 2\varepsilon i.
$$
Taking $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives us the answer, BUT we do have to be a bit careful in taking this limit. If we parametrize the curve $\gamma_\varepsilon$ as a function $z : [\varepsilon, 2\pi - \varepsilon] \to \mathbb{C}$, $z(\theta) = re^{i\theta}$, we can rewrite our integral as
$$
\int_{\varepsilon}^{2\pi - \varepsilon} \frac{1}{z(\theta)}z'(\theta)d\theta
= 2\pi i - 2\varepsilon i.
$$
Because the integrand's value is bounded as $\varepsilon \to 0$, we are justified in saying that
$$
\int_C f(z)dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{z(\theta)}z'(\theta)d\theta
= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_\varepsilon^{2\pi - \varepsilon} \frac{1}{z(\theta)}z'(\theta)d\theta= 2\pi i.
$$

In general, I would say that a function can be “integrated normally” only when the function has a primitive on the entire contour. But oftentimes, you can cut corners (quite literally) when the function has a primitive *almost everywhere*. I admittedly do like your professor's second method. Although it may not be as “rigorous,” there is a very clear intuitive reason for why it works.

Comment: very last equal sign should be $2\pi i$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed :)